# Errors occur submit batch request

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to use batch request for sending http post to the server.

The code snippet, which generate the request:

```
   _.each(aNewDates, function (oNew) {
     oModel.create("/CostCenterCalendarSet", oNew, {
       groupId: "newDates"
     });
   });
   oModel.setDeferredGroups(["newDates"]);
```

and the submit method:

```
oModel.submitChanges({
  groupId: "newDates",
  oSuccess: function (oMsg) {
    return observer.next(oMsg);
  },
  oError: function (oErr) {
    return observer.error(oErr);
  },
});
```

as response I've got following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I tried with ODataModel `read` method and does not get any result.

```
          let oPlantFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedData.sPlant);
          let oWcFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("WorkCenter", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedData.sWc);

          oModel.read("/CostCenterCalendarSet", {
            groupId: "query-dates",
            filters: [oPlantFilter, oWcFilter]
          });

          oModel.setDeferredGroups(["query-dates"]);

          return Rx.Observable.create(function (subscriber) {
            oModel.submitChanges({
              groupId: "query-dates",
              success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                return subscriber.next(oResponse);
              },
              error: function (oErr) {
                return subscriber.error(oErr);
              },
            });
          });
```

Comment: Looking at the error, could you do type check for the value you are sending for `create` (some field is expecting Number and you are not sending it). Then coming to read, you have to debug in the backend I hope.